# Roots of a function despite first derivative imaginary regions.

Tags: derivatives, roots

If a function has roots which satisfy it, yet some of those roots fall in a region that the first derivative is imaginary/unknown, then will those roots count as part of the solution?

Example: The below equation has roots: 2,3,4,5, and 6.  (Note the exponent can be factored as (x-6)(x-5))
Now the first derivative (Used Mathematica) does not have solutions of **x^2-7x+11<=0** (due to both the denominator and Log components). And the region which that is true for is **between (7-sqrt(5))/2 and (7+sqrt(5))/2 , ~(2.38,4.62)** - Hence this will result in discarding both 3 and 4 as part of the solution, since they both fall in that region. Is this correct? (if so, why do both 3 and 4 nicely satisfy the original equation, yet the graph is unknown for that region).

Does this mean we always have to evaluate the first derivative of a function all the time, in order to verify discontinuity, despite having correct roots? Also: If that is the case, wouldn't that mean that we have to in-turn evaluate the 2nd derivative also, in order to ensure that the first derivative itself will not have the same issue? ...and Nth derivative, by the same logic?

Function:

$$y=-1+(x^2-7x+11)^{(x^2-11x+30)}$$

First derivative:

$$ (11 - 7 x + x^2)^{(
 30 - 11 x + 
  x^2)} (((-7 + 2 x) (30 - 11 x + x^2))/(
   11 - 7 x + x^2)) + (-11 + 2 x) Log[11 - 7 x + x^2] $$

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVrUv.jpg)

[First Derivative Unknown region - x^2-7x+11 <=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Ok9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 and 4 ARE ROOTS on the graph (they are 0), and there are a few sporadic points that will be real as well (at like 3.4 for example), but since they are infinitely small and surrounded by nonreal points, you will likely not see them on a graphing utility. If you see below, the only parts that will show are the parts where the imaginary graph is at 0.

[Here is Re[F(x)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV2jl.png)

[And Here is the Im[F(x)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne1u5.png)

In conclusion: No. Your roots are still your roots regardless of how wacky the graph might look.

Comment: Ok thanks @Neptune. So a few things: 1) Would you agree the original graph has only 2 points/dots on the 3,4, as it is so small, it is not shown on the graph? Can we not make Mathematica zoom in and show the 2 dots? 2) When we find roots, we normally should not care about the first derivative then? And not find the Real part of the function's roots? 3) So what is the slope of a single point? I assume it is unknown since the first derivative is not real?

Comment: 4) When I draw the Real part of this function I see 6 intersection points in between 3 and 4, [Re{}](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Chjo4pQaP_46MV_S0LilRCHPkXs5pANO/view?usp=sharing), why are these not all part of the roots?

Comment: @Steve237 1)Yeah. I'm not sure how Mathematica works, but most graphing utilities probably won't show it unless you actually find a setting that will blow up individual points. 2) If you are trying to graph a function off of its roots, first derivative can be helpful in determining whether it is increasing, decreasing, or just stationary at the root so you can go around it, but it doesn't influence whether or not something equals 0. 3) If slope is defined as it usually is, there is no concept of it for a single point, but you could find the real partial if you wanted, which would look ...

Comment: @Steve237... something like a slope on a 3d or 4d graph. 4) Some of the intersection points are 0 for real, but have a complex part, meaning they are not actually 0 (a root). For example, with x^2 + x + i if you plug in 0, your Real part will = 0, but your complex part will be i.

Comment: Thx @Neptune. It all makes sense. I tried to give Useful comment-ticks above, but don't have rep of 15 yet to do so. By the way, this graph then would have 2 single dots at points 3 and 4 right?

Comment: It would have 1 single dot at point 3 and one single dot at point 4.

Comment: Wow, so just the 2 dots and then undefined inside that range otherwise. By the way 1 more thing: are non-continuous functions differentiable (such as this)? There certainly is the first derivative function but it's also not defined for certain ranges. are we in general allowed to differentiate non-continuous functions?

Comment: 1) Within the range, there are a few other points that are defined (see when imaginary goes to 0), they just aren't roots because the real part isn't also zero. 2) You can get the derivative for portions of a function (piecewise differentiation with the function defined piecewise), or for a function like this (continuous in C), you can get $\frac {\partial f}{\partial z}$ as well as for$ z = x+iy$ you can get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$